# Best way to read/write file in multithreaded environment (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, file-io

i have a multithreaded program that reads and writes files. One thread receives data and writes them in a file. Every 250 Mb of data, a new file is created. Multiple other threads can read into these files to retrieve data. I'm using C++ std file stream.

To prevent problems, my current implementation uses two file descriptors for the same file: one for readers and one for the writer. A mutex protects from multiple access at the same time, and the file descriptor position is moved each time the mutex owner needs it.

I really need to be able to read in the file as fast as possible, and the mutex doesn't really help me.

Firstly, I would like to know if it's safe to read and write the file or have multiple reads at the same time (on every platform).
Secondly, if yes, I would like to know how it is safe for the hardware like the "Disk read-and-write head" for a HDD. The software works on the disk all the time to save data, and i don't want my algorithm to decrease too much the hard disk life time (already short).

Thank you for your help

Comment: 1 thing: don't worry about the pattern of HDD use - the OS will take care of that. But yes, if you significantly increase HDD i/o, you will decrease its lifetime no matter what

Comment: 2 - if you want it to be AS FAST AS POSSIBLE, look into RAMDISKS or even simply loading your data into memory. RAM is cheap, so try to fit it all in there

Comment: to answer your first question - yes it is safe, if you have the proper locking logic. no reading while a write is taking place if the read depends on it, etc.

Comment: Global mutex lock, `std::fstream`... basically that's a list of what *not* to do if you want *fast*.

Comment: to be so fast you either should use a shared memory, or a pipe for each reader, thats the fastest you can get

Comment: @Jon, what do you suggest?

Comment: I need to add that i can have 18 Tera Bytes of files splitted in 250 MB file, and i can access in any file at any time depending on the client request. It is video data, so i can also read a large range of data in different files. So how can i be efficient to deal with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem regarding multiple threads reading the same file.

Now, if I understood your description correctly, you do not modify *already-written* data, you just continuously *append* data to your file until it reaches 250Mb, then you continue writing on a new file.

If this is the case, you may not need a mutex at all. For instance, you might be able to keep your whole "file" into memory until it reaches 250mb, and only then you would write it all to disk, so you know that any files already on disk aren't going to be written anymore and can be read freely with no worries. As for the file that is still being written, you can have a global integer that holds how many bytes (or strings or whatever you use) have already been written, and reading-threads are limited by this integer, which does not need a lock, as long as you only update the integer after you have already written the data. (since you said there is only 1 thread writing data).

Simply reading the integer cannot corrupt it even when being done by multiple threads at the same time and being written by a single one, so this will ensure your reader threads will not read beyond the limit, and such limit will always be safe and consistent, while the writer-thread can peacefully write data in an area that is guaranteed to not be bothered by read-threads until it is finished.

As for your second question, if you are indeed able to keep the currently-being-written file fully in memory, that will already save up some HDD usage, as well as time. Additionally, keep in mind most modern HDDs have 32Mb+ of cache, so it is not like every read and write will be directly hitting the HDD itself, unless you have a ton of threads reading random files and random parts of them all the time. If that is the case, there is probably not much you can do to help the HDD. And if that's not the case, there is not much to worry about, as the OS and the caches will do what they were meant to do :)

Comment: "reading the integer cannot corrupt it even when being done by multiple threads at the same time and being written by a single one" - This is not true. You will get undefined behavior on both C++03 and C++11. You will need at least an atomic integer here.

Comment: Undefined behavior as in, if the read is done at the same time as the writing, it is not defined whether the read will retrieve the old or the new value of the integer. Which are both safe in this case.

Comment: No. Undefined behavior as in: Data-race, anything can happen. You may see *any* value. In particular you may see a value that was never actually written (§1.10.21, ISO/IEC 14882:2011).

Comment: Right, just like integer overflow. He wants to do it *as fast as possible* - in his scenario, this is it. Although I'll give it to you that the atomic overhead would probably not be meaningful compared to the time he spends reading and writing data.

Comment: When two files are on the same HDD, reading both at the same time from different threads while safe, will generally also be slow because the drive will seek back and forth between the two more than it needs to. You probably want one mutex per HDD to get control over how often seeks can happen.

Comment: Thank you all for your advice. I think I will choose the Arthur's solution and keep in memory the file to be written. The application can support unlimited client request, but in practice, in the worst case, i think i can get around a maximum of 30 thread (average is probably) reading the same file. As i said in another comment, this is video data, so the main problem is to deliver streams to multiple client in real time, so for 24 FPS, i will except that reading a frame in the file will take always less than 30 ms, whatever the number of clients.